# 425 error ftp over SSL in Java

Tags: java, apache, ssl, ftp

Using the Apache commons library, I am attempting to put a file or to list directory contents on the remote server that is connected using FTP over SSL.

```
public void outboundProcessFile(String inputFilePath, String outputFilePath) throws Exception {

File inFile = new java.io.File(inputFilePath);
if (args == null){
    System.exit(-1) ;
}
String args[] = this.args;

boolean storeFile = false, binaryTransfer = false, error = false, listFiles = false, listNames = false, hidden = false;
boolean mlst = false, mlsd = false;
boolean lenient = true;
boolean feat = true;;
long keepAliveTimeout = 300000;
int controlKeepAliveReplyTimeout = 300000;
int minParams = 5; 
String doCommand = "PROT P";//null
String server = null, password = null, username = null, remote = null,local = null;
int port = 990;//990
int base = 0;
for (base = 0; base < args.length; base++)     {
    if (args[base].equals("-s")) {
        storeFile = true;
    }        else if (args[base].equals("-b")) {
        binaryTransfer = true;
    }        else if (args[base].equals("-c")) {
        doCommand = args[++base];
        minParams = 3;
    }        else if (args[base].equals("-d")) {
        mlsd = true;
        minParams = 3;
    }        else if (args[base].equals("-h")) {
        hidden = true;
    }        else if (args[base].equals("-k")) {
        keepAliveTimeout = Long.parseLong(args[++base]);
    }        else if (args[base].equals("-l")) {
        listFiles = true;
        minParams = 3;
    }        else if (args[base].equals("-L")) {
        lenient = true;
    }        else if (args[base].equals("-n")) {
        listNames = true;
        minParams = 3;
    }        else if (args[base].equals("-t")) {
        mlst = true;
        minParams = 3;
    }        else if (args[base].equals("-w")) {
        controlKeepAliveReplyTimeout = Integer.parseInt(args[++base]);
    }        else if (args[base].equals("-sh")) {
        server = args[++base];
        String parts[] = server.split(":");
        if (parts.length == 2){
            server=parts[0];
            port=Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
        }
    }        else if (args[base].equals("-u")) {
        username = args[++base];
    }        else if (args[base].equals("-pw")) {
        password = args[++base];
    }        else if (args[base].equals("-rf")) {
        remote = null;

        if (args.length - base > 0) {
            remote = args[++base];
        }
    }        else if (args[base].equals("-lf")) {
        local = null;

        if (args.length - base > 0) {
            local = args[++base];
        }
    }        else {
        break;
    }
}

FTPClient ftp;
    FTPSClient ftps = new FTPSClient(true);

    ftp = ftps;
    ftps.setTrustManager(TrustManagerUtils.getAcceptAllTrustManager());
    ftp.setCopyStreamListener(createListener());

if (keepAliveTimeout >= 0) {
    ftp.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(keepAliveTimeout);
}
if (controlKeepAliveReplyTimeout >= 0) {
    ftp.setControlKeepAliveReplyTimeout(controlKeepAliveReplyTimeout);
}
ftp.setListHiddenFiles(hidden);

// suppress login details
ftp.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out), true));

try                                  {
    int reply;
    if (port > 0) {
        ftp.connect(server, port);
    } else {
        ftp.connect(server);
    }
    System.out.println("Connected to " + server + " on "+ftp.getRemotePort());

    // After connection attempt, you should check the reply code to verify
    // success.
    reply = ftp.getReplyCode();

    if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply))           {
        ftp.disconnect();
        System.err.println("FTP server refused connection.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
catch (IOException e)         {
    if (ftp.isConnected())         {
        try               {
            ftp.disconnect();
        }
        catch (IOException f)
        {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
    System.err.println("Could not connect to server.");
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(1);
}

__main:
try
{
    String userid = null;//

    if (!ftp.login(username, password))              {
        ftp.logout();
        error = true;
        break __main;
    }

    System.out.println("Remote system is " + ftp.getSystemType());
    if (feat)                                                        {
        // boolean feature check
        if (remote != null) { // See if the command is present
            if (ftp.hasFeature(remote)) {
                System.out.println("Has feature: "+remote);
            } else {
                if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(ftp.getReplyCode())) {
//                        System.out.println("FEAT "+remote+" was not detected");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Command failed: "+ftp.getReplyString());
                }
            }

            // Strings feature check
            String []features = ftp.featureValues(remote);
            if (features != null) {
                for(String f : features) {
                    System.out.println("FEAT "+remote+"="+f+".");
                }
            } else {
                if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(ftp.getReplyCode())) {
//                        System.out.println("FEAT "+remote+" is not present");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Command failed: "+ftp.getReplyString());
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (ftp.features()) {
//                    Command listener has already printed the output
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed: "+ftp.getReplyString());
            }
        }
    }
    ftp.doCommandAsStrings("PBSZ", "0");
    ftp.doCommandAsStrings("PROT", "P");
    if (binaryTransfer)
        ftp.setFileType(FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE);//.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

    // Use passive mode as default because most of us are
    // behind firewalls these days.

        ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftp.doCommand("MLSD", "");

    if (storeFile)          {
        InputStream input;

        input = new FileInputStream(local);
        ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(remote);
        ftp.storeFile(local.substring(local.lastIndexOf("/")+1), input);

        input.close();
    }        else if (listFiles)          {
        if (lenient) {
            FTPClientConfig config = new FTPClientConfig();
            config.setLenientFutureDates(true);
            ftp.configure(config );
        }

        for (FTPFile f : ftp.listFiles(remote)) {
            System.out.println(f.getRawListing());
            System.out.println(f.toFormattedString());
        }
    }         else if (mlsd)         {
        for (FTPFile f : ftp.mlistDir(remote)) {
            System.out.println(f.getRawListing());
            System.out.println(f.toFormattedString());
        }
    }           else if (mlst)          {
        FTPFile f = ftp.mlistFile(remote);
        if (f != null){
            System.out.println(f.toFormattedString());
        }
    }               else if (listNames)           {
        for (String s : ftp.listNames(remote)) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }    else          {
        OutputStream output;

        output = new FileOutputStream(local);
        ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(remote);
        ftp.retrieveFile(local.substring(local.lastIndexOf("/")), output);

        output.close();
    }

    ftp.noop(); // check that control connection is working OK
    ftp.logout();
}       catch (FTPConnectionClosedException e)       {
    error = true;
    System.err.println("Server closed connection.");
    e.printStackTrace();
}     catch (IOException e)        {
    error = true;
    e.printStackTrace();
}     finally         {
    if (ftp.isConnected())         {
        try               {
            ftp.disconnect();
        }             catch (IOException f)             {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
}
System.exit(error? -1:0);       
   }
```

I run this and get console output for listing...

```
220 Serv-U FTP Server v6.4 for WinSock ready...
Connected to ftps.server.com on 990
USER *******
331 User name okay, need password.
PASS *******
230 User logged in, proceed.
SYST
215 UNIX Type: L8
Remote system is UNIX Type: L8
FEAT
211-Extension supported
 AUTH TLS
 SSCN
 PBSZ
 PROT
 CCC
 CLNT
 MDTM
 MDTM YYYYMMDDHHMMSS[+-TZ];filename
 SIZE
 SITE PSWD;EXEC;SET;INDEX;ZONE;CHMOD;MSG
 REST STREAM
 XCRC filename;start;end
 MODE Z
 MLST Type*;Size*;Create;Modify*;Win32.ea*;
211 End
PBSZ 0
200 PBSZ command OK. Protection buffer size set to 0.
PROT P
200 PROT command OK. Using private data connection.
TYPE A
200 Type set to A.
MLSD 
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for MLSD.
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (204,124,192,88,195,82)
LIST Directory/toIC/
425 Try later, data connection in use.
NOOP
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for MLSD.
QUIT
200 Command okay.
```

If I do not MLSD and attempt to upload a file, I will see a 0 byte file with the file name placed on the server (via FileZilla) and I will get a 421 error. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove the MLSD command.  I can now list, retrieve and stor.