# Java code to connect to FTP server using SSL

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

I am looking for Java sample code to connect to FTP server using SSL certificate. I have all needed certificates in my project folder. I tried some approach, but it doesnt work. We are using Spring batch component. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
protected FTPSClient createFTPClient() throws Exception {
 FTPSClient client = new FTPSClient(protocol,true); 
 client.setNeedClientAuth(true);
 KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS"); 
 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(keyStoreFile);
 ks.load(fis, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
 fis.close();
 KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory .getDefaultAlgorithm());
 kmf.init(ks, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
 client.setKeyManager(kmf.getKeyManagers()[0]);
 return client; 
}

int reply; 
FTPSClient ftps = null;
try { 
  ftps = createFTPClient();
  ftps.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));       
  //ftps.setTrustManager(trustManager) 
  ftps.connect(host,portnumber);
  ......
```

I am getting Plaintext connection exception....

Comment: If you already tried it, you should post the code (and maybe the exception stacktrace)!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Below is the code:

 protected FTPSClient createFTPClient() throws Exception { 
    FTPSClient client = new FTPSClient(protocol,true); 
    client.setNeedClientAuth(true); 

    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS"); 
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(keyStoreFile); 
    ks.load(fis, keyStorePassword.toCharArray()); 
    fis.close(); 

    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory 
            .getDefaultAlgorithm()); 
    kmf.init(ks, keyStorePassword.toCharArray()); 

    client.setKeyManager(kmf.getKeyManagers()[0]); 

    return client; 
}

Comment: int reply;
    FTPSClient ftps = null;
    try {
 ftps = createFTPClient();

      
      ftps.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));
      //ftps.setTrustManager(trustManager)
      
      ftps.connect(host,portnumber);

......} I am getting Plaintext connection exception....

Answer (score 0):

I got this from this different question [425 error ftp over SSL in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196630/425-error-ftp-over-ssl-in-java)

```
ftps.setTrustManager(TrustManagerUtils.getAcceptAllTrustManager());
```

It might help.